# problem with laravel view not extending layout.blade.php with out assets file . What can possibly be the problem?

Tags: laravel, routes, view, controller, laravel-blade

for my college project , I am using a template view called (home_layout.blade.php) to be my layout for other views , it was working well before but i made a new view and when extending the home_layout view :

```html
@extends('pharmacy.home_layout')
@section('content')

<article class="wow fadeIn animated hover-up mb-30 animated">
    <!-- Post Thumbnail -->
    <div class="post-thumb" style="background-image: url('{{ asset('storage/' . $item->up_image) }}');">
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <a class='entry-meta meta-2' href='/blog-category-grid'></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Post Content -->
    <div class="entry-content-2 pl-50">
        <!-- Post Title -->
        <h3 class="post-title mb-20">
            <a href='/blog-post-right'>{{$item->up_name}}</a>
        </h3>

        <!-- Trade Name -->
        <h5> اسم المنتج التجاري</h5>
        <p class="post-exerpt mb-40">{{$item->up_trade_name}}</p>

        <!-- Description -->
        <h5> الوصف</h5>
        <p class="post-exerpt mb-40">{{$item->description}}</p>

        <!-- Meta Information -->
        <div class="entry-meta meta-1 font-xs color-grey mt-10 pb-10"> 
            <div>
                <span class="post-on">{{$item->up_publish_date}}</span>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

@endsection
```

it looks like this :

[image: result without extending]

note: i have already extended the blade layout tin other views and it works properly.

now it is no working

[image: result with extending]

I  tried making new files , but same thing happens.

Comment: Could you share the content of `pharmacy.home_layout`

Comment: it is a file of 1000 lines, how can I share it with you ?

Comment: Oh, too long. I could see the URL of the page with issues. Could you also show the URL of the page that works?  I don't want to visit the URL, I just want to know if this is related to assets. Does it only affect the assets?

Comment: yes I think it only affects the assets> here's the url of the working page :
[link](http://pharmreach-v2.test/pharmacy/posts)